# Oracle Apex Dynamic actions - forcing synchronous execution

Tags: oracle-apex

I have a set of page items:

```
P1_ERRORS
P1_ERROR_COUNT
P1_RESULT
```

If P1_ERRORS is updated, then a dynamic action fires on P1_ERRORS change to calculate P1_ERROR_COUNT.

A dynamic action is set on P1_ERROR_COUNT to calculate if the P1_RESULT should be "PASS" or "FAIL" based on the error count.

I then have a another Page Item:

```
P1_IGNORE
```

If P1_IGNORE is set to "YES", the dynamic action on P1_IGNORE clears P1_ERRORS, and sets P1_RESULT to "N\A".

What happens is, P1_RESULT briefly changes to "N\A" then reverts back to "PASS".

So P1_IGNORE clears P1_ERRORS, this fires the change event on P1_ERRORS to recalculate P1_ERROR_COUNT, P1_ERROR_COUNT dynamic action fires, sees error count as zero and so sets P1_RESULT to PASS.

So when P1_IGNORE changes another page item, those DAs are getting kicked off, and then a race condition happens.  P1_IGNORE does terminate its dynamic action by setting P1_RESULT to "N\A", but then the other DAs complete later and set it back to "PASS".

While I can solve this using client side conditions on some DA actions (messy), is there a way to force this cascading of change events and dynamic actions to happen synchronously rather than asynchronously??  i.e. if DA 1 updates DA 2, can I wait for any dynamic actions on DA 2 to fire before continuing the actions in DA 1.

Comment: "While I can solve this using client side conditions on some DA actions (messy)" >> that's what I was going to suggest.

Comment: @Littlefoot I was thinking maybe a common dynamic action that deals with everything, and gets called by javascript by other DAs may be better, but none of this would be necessary if you could make one DA act synchronously with any DAs it causes the firing of via change events

Comment: Have a look at the debounce option for dynamic actions, that could help you out.

Comment: How does P1_ERRORS get populated ?

Comment: its a check box, it gets populated with static items, when someone clicks an error, it counts the number of errors selected in a DA, and the DA updates P1_ERROR_COUNT

Comment: @KoenLostrie doesn't that just delay the call to a DA, meaning it would be guesswork or luck to find the right value?

Comment: pretty sure debounce isnt what I need, I need the actions in the first DA, to somehow wait for change events and DAs it triggers before proceeding to the next action, not just delay the input before starting

Answer (score 0):

It's best to split up the 2 decision chains.

Current issue:

Chain 1: P1_ERRORS updates P1_ERROR_COUNT updates P1_RESULT
Chain 2: P1_INGORE updates P1_ERRORS and this fires chain 1.

One solution:

Add an additional page item P1_CALCULATE_ERRORS. Update this page item together with P1_ERRORS (not via a DA on P1_ERRORS !) and use that to calculate P1_ERROR_COUNT and P1_RESULT

Chain 1: P1_CALCULATE_ERRORS updates P1_ERROR_COUNT updates P1_RESULT
Chain 2: P1_IGNORE updates P1_RESULT directly

Comment: Thanks, appreciate it.  I know I can do some tricks like re-organise the chain, add client side conditions.  Guess I was hoping for a nice setting on a DA to allow it to be conscious of the actions it kicked off, and act synchronously on any change events its sub processes kicked off on other page items

Comment: Nope, no settings. But honestly, making it logically as clean as possible is the way to go - that is going to save you headaches later on.

Comment: There is a little reorg to do, and surpress change events may work in certain instances to stop the cascade